# Why Service is calling multiple times when clicking on Kendo ui grid pagination

Tags: kendo-grid

let

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({   
           type: "json",
           transport: {
               read: {
                   type: 'POST',
                   dataType: 'json',
                    url: url,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    beforeSend: function (xhr: any) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Token', that.userToken.sessionID)
                    }
                    // Token: that.userToken.sessionID ? that.userToken.sessionID : '',
                },
                parameterMap: function (data: any, type: any) {
                    console.log(type);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    if(type === "read"){
                        let paramObj = {
                            "request": {
                                skip: data.skip,
                                page: data.page,
                                pageSize: data.pageSize,
                                filter: searchDetails
                            },
                            "userToken": that.userToken
                        };
                        return kendo.stringify(paramObj);
                    }
                }
           },
           schema: {
                parse: function(response: any) {
                    return response.jsonObj.response.response;
                },
                total: function (response: any) {
                    return response.numFound ? response.numFound : 0
                },
                data: function (response: any) {
                    return that.formatResponse(response.docs);
                }
            },          
            pageSize: 100,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
       });
```

Comment: What is this @Question Owner ?

Answer (score 0):

serverPaging, serverFiltering and serverSorting are set to true so all those operations will be executed on the server side instead of in the client.